# Perl replace value without updating array

Tags: perl, lexical-scope

I have the following Perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @fruits = qw(apple banana orange pear);

print Dumper \@fruits;

foreach my $fruit (@fruits) {
  $fruit =~ s|apple|peach|;
}

print Dumper \@fruits;
```

The following is returned.

```
$VAR1 = [
          'apple',
          'banana',
          'orange',
          'pear'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'peach',
          'banana',
          'orange',
          'pear'
        ];
```

I do not understand why the following line has changed apple to peach in the @fruits array, as I thought this line would only apply to the $fruit variable, not the @fruits array.

```
$fruit =~ s|apple|peach|;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the html doc of perl we have the following statement for foreach loops:

> the foreach loop index variable is an implicit alias for each item in the list that you're looping over

This means, you do not get a copy of each array element. The variable `$fruit` is only a reference to an array element. Its value can be modified if the array element can be modified. The modification applies to the original array element.

Comment: Got it, makes sense now. Within the foreach loop, I will define `my $inner = $fruit;` and then apply the modification to the $inner variable `$inner =~ s|apple|peach|g;`. Thanks much for the assistance here!

Comment: You could use the `/r` regex modifier to do it in one go, e.g. `my $inner = $fruit =~ s|apple|peach|gr;`  (although I find `s{apple}{peach}gr` a more readable way personally))

Comment: If you did get a copy, the code would do nothng